# estoy tratando de programar soy nuevo y me aparece el mismo error para poder terminar a clippy

Tags: windows, aplicación-escritorio

def mostrar_mensaje_ayuda(): messagebox.showinfo("Clippy", "¡Hola! Soy Clippy, tu asistente virtual. ¿En qué puedo ayudarte hoy?")
ventana = tk.Tk() ventana.title("Clippy") ventana.geometry("400x300")
imagen_clippy = Image.open("clippy.png") # Reemplaza "clippy.png" con la ruta de tu propia imagen de Clippy imagen_clippy = imagen_clippy.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS) imagen_clippy = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_clippy)
label_clippy = tk.Label(ventana, image=imagen_clippy) label_clippy.pack()
entrada_usuario = tk.Entry(ventana) entrada_usuario.pack()
boton_ayuda = tk.Button(ventana, text="¿Necesitas ayuda?", command=mostrar_mensaje_ayuda) boton_ayuda.pack()

ventana.mainloop()

Comment: xdddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: Hola, tres cositas, debes agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje y la del toolkit grafico, son mucho mas relevantes que el SO por ejemplo, en este caso python y tkinter. Por otro lado, es esencial que copies y pegues el código tal y como lo tienes, ese código ha perdido la identacion y eso es malo siempre (por legibilidad), pero en python es aun peor... Por ultimo ¿**cual es el error o excepción que tienes exactamente**? [Edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/607188/edit) e intenta agregar esta información.